# ngModel not binding integer value

Tags: mysql, json, angularjs, windows, ubuntu

I am facing a weird problem with angularjs,

I wrote an API with laravel and mysql, wich returns data in json.

On my Ubuntu machine it returns id's and foreign id's as `STRING` in the json response and my ngModel binding works fine.

I recently switched to my windows machine which runs WAMP, here laravel returns id's and foreign id's as `INTEGER` and my ngModel binding does not work anymore.

**Examples**

Laravel json response on `Ubuntu` looks like:

```
{
 "id": "1234",
 "name": "enam",
 ...
}
```

Laravel json response on `Windows` looks like:

```
{
 "id": 1234,
 "name": "enam",
 ...
}
```

I have an input[text] field that binds this response to ngModel like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.user.id" ...>
```

On my Ubuntu machine it works fine, on Windows I get an empty input field.

Did anyone face this problem before ? How could I fix this problem in a clean way ?

I guess I could cast it *.toString();* but that doesn't seem so clean to me.

**The binding in my Controller**

```
vm.getCustomer = function() {
    Customer.getById($stateParams.id)
    .then(function(data) {
        vm.customer = data.data;
    }, function(error) {
        vm.error = error.data;
    });
};
```

And the Customer service just returns an $http call

**Json response (Ubuntu)**

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "enam",
  "postalcode_id": "1179",
  "created_at": "2015-04-09 19:48:47",
  "updated_at": "2015-04-11 18:00:02",
  "postalcode": {
    "id": "1179",
    "postalcode": "1090",
    "city": "JETTE",
    "province": "Brussel (19 gemeenten)"
  }
}
```

And in windows it returns postalcode.postalcode and the id's as `INTEGER`,
It works with the $cast as @Matthew Brown suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than an OS issue specifically this seems to be a browser issue between OS's.

Just fix it on the server side,  if your are using Laravel 5,  you can get away with simply adding a $casts attribute to your model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'id' => 'integer'
];
```

Personally, I like to use transformers for my APIs.  Check out this library called [Fractal](https://github.com/thephpleague/fractal).  This makes including relationships and type casting a dream, plus allows your api to remain the same through future column name changes, etc.

Comment: It did the trick, will look into Fractal more deeply. Although it feels highly inconsistent that Angularjs can't bind integers into an ngModel but bind it correctly to the view. Or am i missing something ?

Comment: Could be missing something, I could perhaps point out the issue of I could see where your model is being set in the controller?

Comment: What version of angular?

Comment: 1.2.28 at the moment. Maybe that's the issue. Will check if that helps and let you know

Comment: Updating angular to 1.3.15 solved the issue indeed, but as i require angular bootstrap to work in my project i'm stuck with 1.2.28 for now